# Main Beam Cut and Settled at Some Point What Are The Options?

Tags: structural-engineering

It looks like someone cut the main beam and there was settling at some point in the past. There is a noticeable dip and cupping in the floor near the main beam in the floors above. Why might someone have done this and what are the trade offs between the various remedies?

As I understand it the range of solutions are

1. Put in permanent steel columns with a 2' x 2' cement footer
2. Replace the main beam
3. Put in a new cement footer across the foundation to prevent further settling.
4. Some other solution

Some extra context; The main beam runs most the length of the house which is 46' in length and 26' in width. It looks like it has been cut about 4' from the end of the house. The house is two stories and the main beam supports a load bearing wall that divides the house approximately in half; the floor plan/load bearing wall is in the same position on each floor. The contractors that have taken a look at did not seem to understand what caused the settling nor did the structural engineer; they just pointed out that it was a problem and did not give any advice or context beyond saying that we should put in permanent columns.

Main beam with temporary columns
[image: Main beam with temporary columns]

Cut main beam; the main beam ends next to the black tar paper
[image: Cut main beam; the main beam ends next to the black tar paper]

Support for the cut beam?
[image: Support for the cut beam?]

Comment: This belongs on Home Improvement

Comment: @SolarMike Feel free to close. I can move it over. Does the engineering stack exchange not cover applied engineering questions, and is instead for theoretical questions?